# Storing a directory structure in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

In my rails app a user can have a directory structure which has folders and files in sub-folders. Which is the best way to store such data ??
Also, which database offers best way to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can store a directory tree in a single table using any SQL database, by making the table self-referential. A good example is the [Windows Installer's Directory table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368295%28VS.85%29.aspx), where you will see a structure like this:

- **Directory** = primary key id field, typically an integer
- **Directory_Parent** = "foreign key" id field, which points to the id of another Directory in the same table
- **Value** = string containing the directory/folder name

Your file table would then have a foreign key referencing the Directory id. To find the full path, you must follow it up the chain and build up the path from the end (right), tacking each parent directory onto the front (left). For example, the file would point to Directory id '4' with the Value 'subfolder', then you fetch the parent's value 'folder', then the parents value again until you get to the root, creating a path like `/root/folder/subfolder/filename`.

Comment: Is there any trick to reduce the number of queries to less than the depth of the file?

Comment: @cyang None that I know of for this self-referential table method. There are, of course, other design possibilities which would look quite different--for example, you could devise a system in which each file gets a totally unique complex name, and thus only a single db table would be needed to store the actual directory location...

Comment: @cyang - You could use this method, but have another field that had the IDs up the chain with a delimiter.  Something like 447:33:2:185 to signify /[folder447]/[folder33]/[etc]/[this folder].  Then you can pull a given folder and its parents in two queries.  Of course, you now have the overhead of creating and managing that field when you create or move the directory, but at least you would only have to do that once per time.  Just don't let it get out of sync with the actual parents.  And yes, before anyone freaks out, it is duplicate data.  It's called a shortcut =o)

Answer (score 2):

If your database supports recursive queries (either Oracle's connect by or the standard recursive common table expressions) then a self referencing table is fine (it's easy to update and query).

If your DBMS does not support hierarchical queries, then Eimantas suggestion to use a preordered tree traversal scheme is probably the best way.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple tree stored in sql. Either check the standard `parent-child` scheme or implement preordered tree traversal scheme (left-right).