# SQLite: Create Directory Structure Table from A List Of Paths

Tags: database, sqlite, csv, directory, structure

I want to create a *directory structure* table as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343087/storing-a-directory-structure-in-database) where: 

**Directory** = "Primary Key" id field, typically an integer
**Directory_Parent** = "Foreign Key" id field, which points to the id of another Directory in the same table
**Value** = string containing the directory/folder name

Given **Tree/Fruit/Apples/**

```
Directory | Directory_Parent | Value
0           null               Root
1           0                  Tree
2           1                  Fruit
3           2                  Apples
```

A **Root** folder has been created at Primary Key 0 with a null parent.

---

My paths are being imported from CSV and currently are in a table with 2 columns:

```
 FileID  Path
      1  videos/gopro/father/mov001.mp4
      2  videos/gopro/father/mov002.mp4
      3  pictures/family/father/Oldman.jpg
      4  pictures/family/father/Oldman2.jpg
      5  documents/legal/father/estate/will.doc
      6  documents/legal/father/estate/will2.doc
      7  documents/legal/father/estate/newyork/albany/will.doc
      8  video/gopro/father/newyork/albany/holiday/christmas/2002/mov001.mp4
      9  pictures/family/father/newyork/albany/holiday/christmas/2002/july/Oldman.jpg
      10 pictures/family/father/newyork/albany/holiday/christmas/2002/june/Oldman2.jpg
```

This table contains 1 million file entries. 
**What's a fast & optimized way to parse this data and move the folder structure into a new table as described above?**

In this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=14b68025073d0013eb6f8734cb27853e) the folders are separated by "/" and moved into a new column, if that helps.

Comment: I don't think it would work in pure sql and if it works, it won't be optimized. I think better do it with a scripting language so you can utilize caching the ids of the generated folders. You will need a dictionary to map the folders to ids in O(1).

Comment: Do you want the filename also in the table or only the directories? Also, you tagged both MySql and SQLite. A solution that would work in both databases is, in my opinion, impossible.

Comment: @forpas Ideally, filenames get isolated to a different table which consists of only the FileID Int Primary Key, parent folder ID (foreign key), and the string file name. The table from this question should only contain directory data, so it's small and can build a Directory Tree (like you see in an Explorer window). When you click on a specific folder, then files from that directory will be loaded/shown from the Database (the table with 1 million files)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL lacks the flexibility and tools of a programming language, which would provide a fast and optimized solution to this problem.

Moreover SQLite is the poorest of the databases when it comes to string manipulation because it does not support a function like SQL Server's [`STRING_SPLIT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or MySql's [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) which would be very helpful.

Nevertheless the problem is interesting and I gave it a shot.

I create the table `dir_struct` with this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE dir_struct (
  Directory INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  Directory_Parent INTEGER REFERENCES dir_struct(Directory), 
  Value TEXT
);
```

and I insert the `'root'` row:

```
INSERT INTO dir_struct (Directory, Directory_Parent, Value) VALUES (0, null, 'root');
```

Also, I turn `OFF` foreign key enforcement with:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;
```

although it is by default turned off, just in case.

First you need a recursive CTE that splits the paths to individual directories (much like the answer on your previous question).
Then in the 2nd CTE, with conditional aggregation, each directory goes in its own column (with the limitation of max 10 directories).
The 3d CTE removes duplicates and the 4th CTE assigns, with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function, unique ids to the directories.
Finally with a self join of the results of the 4th CTE, the rows are inserted in the table:

```
WITH 
  split AS (
    SELECT 0 idx,
           FileDataID,
           SUBSTR(SUBSTR(Path, 1), 1, INSTR(SUBSTR(Path, 1), '/') - 1) item,
           SUBSTR(SUBSTR(Path, 1), INSTR(SUBSTR(Path, 1), '/') + 1) value
    FROM listfile
    UNION ALL
    SELECT idx + 1,
           FileDataID,
           SUBSTR(value, 1, INSTR(value, '/') - 1),
           SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, '/') + 1)
    FROM split
    WHERE value LIKE '%_/_%' 
  ),
  cols AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
           MAX(CASE WHEN idx = 0 THEN item END) path0,
           MAX(CASE WHEN idx = 1 THEN item END) path1,
           MAX(CASE WHEN idx = 2 THEN item END) path2,
           MAX(CASE WHEN idx = 3 THEN item END) path3,
           MAX(CASE WHEN idx = 4 THEN item END) path4,
           MAX(CASE WHEN idx = 5 THEN item END) path5,
           MAX(CASE WHEN idx = 6 THEN item END) path6,
           MAX(CASE WHEN idx = 7 THEN item END) path7,
           MAX(CASE WHEN idx = 8 THEN item END) path8,
           MAX(CASE WHEN idx = 9 THEN item END) path9
    FROM split
    GROUP BY FileDataID
  ),
  paths AS (
    SELECT path0, path1, path2, path3, path4, path5, path6, path7, path8, path9 FROM cols UNION
    SELECT path0, path1, path2, path3, path4, path5, path6, path7, path8, null FROM cols UNION
    SELECT path0, path1, path2, path3, path4, path5, path6, path7, null, null FROM cols UNION
    SELECT path0, path1, path2, path3, path4, path5, path6, null, null, null FROM cols UNION
    SELECT path0, path1, path2, path3, path4, path5, null, null, null, null FROM cols UNION
    SELECT path0, path1, path2, path3, path4, null, null, null, null, null FROM cols UNION
    SELECT path0, path1, path2, path3, null, null, null, null, null, null FROM cols UNION
    SELECT path0, path1, path2, null, null, null, null, null, null, null FROM cols UNION
    SELECT path0, path1, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null FROM cols UNION
    SELECT path0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null FROM cols
  ), 
  ids AS (
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY path0, path1, path2, path3, path4, path5, path6, path7, path8, path9) nr,
           COALESCE(path9, path8, path7, path6, path5, path4, path3, path2, path1, path0) last_child,
           path0 || COALESCE('/' || path1, '') ||
                    COALESCE('/' || path2, '') ||
                    COALESCE('/' || path3, '') ||
                    COALESCE('/' || path4, '') ||
                    COALESCE('/' || path5, '') ||
                    COALESCE('/' || path6, '') ||
                    COALESCE('/' || path7, '') ||
                    COALESCE('/' || path8, '') ||
                    COALESCE('/' || path9, '') full_path
    FROM paths       
  )
INSERT INTO dir_struct(Directory, Directory_Parent, Value)
SELECT i1.nr, COALESCE(i2.nr, 0), i1.last_child
FROM ids i1 LEFT JOIN ids i2
ON i1.full_path = i2.full_path || '/' || i1.last_child
```

In my test dataset which consists of 187365 rows, the rows were inserted in (average) 9.5-10 minutes, which will be much longer for your larger dataset.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6d841d37efd09b524e1de2e92c748cb8).

What is more interesting is that with simpler code, the performance is worse (but you can also test it):

```
WITH 
  split AS (
    SELECT Path,
           0 parent_len,
           SUBSTR(SUBSTR(Path, 1), 1, INSTR(SUBSTR(Path, 1), '/') - 1) item,
           SUBSTR(SUBSTR(Path, 1), INSTR(SUBSTR(Path, 1), '/') + 1) value
    FROM listfile
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Path,
           parent_len + LENGTH(item) + 1, 
           SUBSTR(value, 1, INSTR(value, '/') - 1),
           SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, '/') + 1)
    FROM split
    WHERE value LIKE '%_/_%' 
  ), 
  row_numbers AS (
    SELECT parent_path, item, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY parent_path, item) rn
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(Path, 1, parent_len) parent_path, item FROM split)       
  )
INSERT INTO dir_struct(Directory, Directory_Parent, Value)  
SELECT r1.rn, COALESCE(r2.rn, 0) rn_parent, r1.item 
FROM row_numbers r1 LEFT JOIN row_numbers r2
ON r1.parent_path = r2.parent_path || r2.item || '/'
```

The ids assigned to the directories by this query are different than the ones assigned by the first solution, but they are correct and unique.

This runs in (average) 14-15 minutes.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e6a3d5476e6b76ca3c115d69ca1d2284).

The conclusion is that if this is a one time thing, maybe you can use it, but I would not recommend it as a solution to this requirement.

Comment: This goes above and beyond what is expected of a stackoverflow answer. I've learned a lot and am indebted and grateful that you've shared your time, knowledge, and expertise here. Thank you VERY much!

Comment: This completed in 10 mins on 1 million files. forpas is a SQL master!!

Comment: @forpas how did you record the time in minutes? are you able to share your test dataset to replicate your experiment?

Comment: @ggordon I use DB Browser for SQLite which reports the time in milliseconds of every query after it is finished. My test dataset consists of all the directories in my hard disk. And no, I can't share it.

Comment: @forpas Thank you. I will replicate with a different dataset with this tool. I'm trying to better understand why the second solution which you identified as simpler had a longer running time. Is it because of the "limitation of max 10 directories" in the first solution?

Comment: @ggordon both solutions have this limitation. The limitation is necessary, although it is arbitrary, because a query returns a fixed number of columns. I still don't know why the 2nd solution performs worse.