# SQLite: Create File Structure Table from String Path. New query or modify existing?

Tags: sqlite, csv, file, directory, structure

I have a SQLite table:

```
FileDataID | Path
0            /FileAtRoot.txt
1            /video/gopro/father/mov001.mp4
2            /pictures/family/father/Oldman.jpg
3            /documents/legal/father/estate/will.doc
```

Using an [elegant solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65769179/sqlite-create-directory-structure-table-from-a-list-of-paths) designed by [forpas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10498828/forpas), a new table consisting of only the directory structure is created:

```
Directory | Directory_Parent | Value
0           null               root
1           0                  documents
2           1                  legal
3           2                  father
...
```

*Reference: [SQLite: Create Directory Structure Table from A List Of Paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65769179/sqlite-create-directory-structure-table-from-a-list-of-paths)*

Now that a table of the directory structure exists, I need to link the original files to their parent by using a foreign key *Directory_Parent* in a new table:

```
FileDataID | Directory_Parent | Value
0            0                  FileAtRoot.txt
1            19                 mov001.mp4
2            9                  Oldman.jpg
3            4                  will.doc
```

**How can I create this table from the original data using SQLite?**

- Can forpas's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65769179/sqlite-create-directory-structure-table-from-a-list-of-paths) be modified so it creates both tables at once?
- Or should this 2nd "file_struct" table be created in a 2nd SQLite query?

  A 1 megabyte example database can be found [here](http://nurfacegames.com/files/ExampleDB.db):
  *A bounty will be awarded for helping with this final question, thank you.*

Comment: Then in example, you have `mov001.mp4` file and it's necessary only to map the Directory ID of its parent folder that is `father`. Is it right?

Comment: Correct, but the entire path up to root must be verified because there are multiple directories with the name "Father".

Comment: could you share the sqlite db, with the two tables? Only some rows for each one

Comment: A 1 megabyte example database can be found here http://nurfacegames.com/files/ExampleDB.db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, you must have already the table `dir_struct` (from your previous question) so that the file names can be inserted to the table with the id of the directory they belong to.

First I create the new table `files`:

```
CREATE TABLE files(
  FileDataID INTEGER REFERENCES listfile(FileDataID), 
  Directory_Parent INTEGER REFERENCES dir_struct(Directory), 
  Value
);
```

You must also create a unique index for `FileDataID` in `listfile`, because it is not defined as the `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE`, so columns in other tables (like the column `FileDataID` of `files`) can reference it.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_listfile_FileDataID ON listfile(FileDataID);
```

A recursive `CTE` is used to query `dir_struct` and build all the possible paths and it is joined to `listfile` to match the file names and their paths:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT Directory, Directory_Parent, Value, '' full_path 
  FROM dir_struct
  WHERE Directory = 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT d.Directory, d.Directory_Parent, d.Value, full_path || d.Value || '/'
  FROM dir_struct d INNER JOIN cte c
  ON c.Directory = d.Directory_Parent
)
INSERT INTO files(FileDataID, Directory_Parent, Value)
SELECT f.FileDataID, c.Directory, SUBSTR(f.Path, LENGTH(c.full_path) + 1)
FROM listfile f INNER JOIN cte c
ON f.Path LIKE c.full_path || '%' AND INSTR(SUBSTR(f.Path, LENGTH(c.full_path) + 1), '/') = 0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=193ff5e148f82d5d7f122af7961ea516), where the code for the insertions in `dir_struct` has also been modified because now the table `listfile` contains files at the root, which did not exist in the sample data of your previous question.

So the code in the demo must be executed **as a whole**.

I used your 1MB sample data and the queries ran very fast.
But, for 1M rows (from the link you first posted), which I also tested (and found duplicates which you must delete before doing anything else), the creation of the table `files` took about 1.5 hour.
As I mentioned in my answer of your previous question, if this is a one time thing then use it. If you will need it frequently, then you should consider something else.